# Symfony ChoiceType form map choices to a related entity field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Not sure if it is possible, but I want to map the two choices of my ChoiceType form two one different `Announcement` field each.

Here is the ChoiceType in a `EditAnnouncementType` I made

```
->add('audience', ChoiceType::class,
        [
            'choices' =>
            [
                'Students: anybody with a student level field populated' => 'students',
                'Employees: anybody with an employee ID number' => 'employees'
            ],
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ])
```

Here are the two fields I want the form to automatically update for the existing `Announcement` entity.

```
class Announcement
{
    /**
     * @param bool $employees
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEmployees(bool $employees)
    {
        $this->employees = $employees;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $students
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStudents(bool $students)
    {
        $this->students = $students;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have this working with two separate CheckBoxType forms instead, however I need to require the user to select **at least one** of the options, which isn't possible (to my knowledge) as two separate forms.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I properly understand what you are asking so let me rephrase it.
You would want your `audience` field to set `employees` to `false` and `students` to `true` in one case, and `employees` to `true` and `students` to `false` in the other case?

If I am correct then here is a possible way to go:

```
class Announcement
{
    public const AUDIENCE_EMPLOYEES = 'employees';
    public const AUDIENCE_STUDENTS = 'students';

    public function getAudience(): array
    {
        $audience = [];

        if($this->employees()) { 
            $audience[] = self::AUDIENCE_EMPLOYEES;
        }
        if($this->employees()) { 
            $audience[] = self::AUDIENCE_STUDENTS;
        }

        return $audience;
    }

    public function setAudience(array $audience): Announcement
    {
        $this->employees = in_array(self::AUDIENCE_EMPLOYEES, $audience);
        $this->students = in_array(self::AUDIENCE_STUDENTS, $audience);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Your `EditAnnouncementType` class should already handle this correctly.
But can be further improved by the usage of class constants

```
->add('audience', ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'choices' =>
        [
            'Students: anybody with a student level field populated' => Announcement::AUDIENCE_STUDENTS,
            'Employees: anybody with an employee ID number' => Announcement::AUDIENCE_EMPLOYEES,
        ],
        'expanded' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ]
)
```

Comment: in a sense, yes that is what I am trying to do. Ideally, I would not need an audience field if that is possible. Also, the user needs to be able to select both choices

Comment: your form types are mapped to entities (or to DTO, but whatever) if you want a form field to represent something, then, yes you fill need a property for that. My bad, I didn't look close enough at the `'multiple' => true,`

Comment: The edited code should do, in order to have a multiple choice possibility